# FFmpeg encoding works fine on a Raspberry Pi 3 but hangs on a Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to encode on my Raspberry Pi 4 but with no success. I've done a test on Raspberry Pi 3 and it works. I'm using the same test file. A `.ts` file from my TVHeadend server containing 3 tracks: 0:0 video h264, 0:1 audio mp2, 0:3 teletext.

I compiled FFmpeg with this configuration for both RPi's:

```
 configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi --enable-nonfree --enable-mmal
```

I start my encode with these commands:

```
 ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -ss 00:01:00 -c:v h264_mmal -i 'test.ts' -to 00:05:00 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:v h264_omx -b:v 1500k -flags +global_header -c:a:0 copy 'test.mp4'
```

FFMPEG starts up but then it hangs, so i have to interrupt it and the screen looks like this:

```
[h264 @ 0x1d570e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x1d570e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1d570e0] no frame!
[mpegts @ 0x1d524b0] PES packet size mismatch
Last message repeated 4 times
Input #0, mpegts, from 'test.ts':
Duration: 00:11:20.09, start: 789.536711, bitrate: 11924 kb/s
Program 101
Metadata:
service_name    : DR1
service_provider: YouSee
Stream #0:0[0x456]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B),
yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps,
25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x457](dan): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz,
stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s
Stream #0:2[0x458](dan): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_mmal) -> h264 (h264_omx))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_mmal @ 0x1d59fc0] Did not get output frame from MMAL.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Unknown error occurred
[h264_mmal @ 0x1d59fc0] Changing output format.
[h264_omx @ 0x1d8da20] Using OMX.broadcom.video_encode
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf58.28.101
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (h264_omx) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p,
1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 1500 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavc58.53.101 h264_omx
Stream #0:1(dan): Audio: mp2 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp,
384 kb/s
```

I can't really figure out why is hanging. I have tried different start commands with or without:

```
fflags +igndts -flags -global_header -flags +global_header
```

I now there is a new Broadcom chip on Raspberry Pi 4. I have turned off for 4K resolution and analog output to see if that made a change, but difference.

So is it me that doing something wrong or is FFmpeg not ready for the new Raspberry Pi 4 / Broadcom chip?